# Reading GeoTIFF from path and converting it into PostGIS raster data type

Tags: raster, postgis, gdal, postgresql, dem

I need to read the raster file (DEM) from path directory and turn it into PostGIS raster data type. I formed this SQL query:

```
SELECT ST_FromGDALRaster(pg_read_binary_file('D:\dems\img.tif')) 
FROM myrasters
```

However, I receive this error: *ERROR:  RASTER_fromGDALRaster: Could not open bytea with GDAL. Check that the bytea is of a GDAL supported format*

When I form query like this:

```
SELECT pg_read_binary_file('D:\dems\img.tif')
FROM myrasters
```

there's no error and I receive bytea. So, the error occurs only when I add ST_FromGDALRaster function.

How can I solve this problem?

I use Windows OS. PostgreSQL 13 version, PostGIS 3.4, GDAL 3.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and I discovered that apparently, GDAL drivers are not enabled by default in PostGIS.

You can view the drivers you have enabled with

```
SELECT * FROM ST_GDALDrivers()
```

You can enable all of them by doing

```
SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';
```

Then run your query and it should work.

edit: note that SET doesn't permanently change this setting.